# Как мне вывести данные из модели Django?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть три страницы, на которых можно проголосовать за 1 объект.
На них вы нажимаете на кнопку "Choose" и результат выводится на главной странице.

black.html

```html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

        <button  class="button_b" name="choose" value="black">
            <h1 style="color: white">
                <strong>Choose</strong>
            </h1>
        </button>

        <h1 style="color: red">{{ count_black }}</h1> <!-- временный просмотр голосов-->
    </form>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Choose(models.Model):
    count_black = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    count_white = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    count_purple = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Моя проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю, как объявить объект модели в views.py.
Мне известно, что вместо "Choose" должна быть переменная, которая берет объекты из класса Choose и использует параметры QuerySet, а так же в последствии использовать эту переменную в context. Однако я не знаю, какие именно параметры мне нужно прописать, чтобы голоса учитывались. Прошу мне помочь.

views.py

```
def black(request):

#пример переменной: name = Choose.objects.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    select_action = request.POST['choose']

    if select_action == 'black':
        Choose.count_black += 1

    # return redirect("home")
Choose.save()

return render(request, 'registration/black.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, вы хотите сделать что-то на подобие этого:

```
def black(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        choose_obj = Choose.objects.first()  # Функция .first()
```

Возвращает первый из `QuerySet` объект. Это в том случае, если голоса будут храниться в одном объекте `Choose`:

```
        select_action = request.POST['choose']

        if select_action == 'black':
            choose_obj.count_black += 1
        choose_obj.save()
    return render(request, 'registration/black.html')
```

Иначе, если вы хотите создавать новый объект на каждый запрос, можете воспользоваться методом `.create()` (`Choose.objects.create()`), внутри которого в качестве аргументов указываете значения атрибутов вашей модели (`count_black`, `count_white`, и т.д.).